# How to remove scientific notation while generating CSV files as output?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I had a delta table which is my input after reading that and generating a output as CSV file i see the scientific notation being displayed if the no of digits exceeds more than 7.
Eg:delta table has column value
a = 22409595 which is a double data type
O/P : CSV is being generated as
a= 2.2409595E7.
I have tried all the possible methods such as format_number,casting etc but unfortunately I haven't succeeded.Using format_number is only working if i had a single record in my output it is not working for multiple records.
Any help on this will appreciated ☺️ thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this and able to remove the scientific notation in the dataframe by converting it to decimal in dataframe.

Please follow the below demonstration below:

**This is my Delta table:**

[image]

You can see, I have the numbers more than 7 in all columns.

**Generating scientific notation in the dataframe:**

[image]

Cast this to Decimal type in the dataframe by which you can specify the count of precision.
Give the count of maximum digits. Here, I have given 10, as my maximum number of digits of number is 10.

[image]

Save this dataframe as csv by which you can get the desired values.

**My Source code:**

```
%sql

CREATE TABLE table1 (col1 double,col2 double,col3 double);

insert into table1 values (22409595,12241226,17161224),(191919213,191919213,191919213);

%python
sqldf=spark.sql("select * from table1")

from pyspark.sql.types import *
for col in sqldf.columns:
    sqldf=sqldf.withColumn(col, sqldf[col].cast(DecimalType(10, 0)))
sqldf.show()
```